# Bootstrap nav tabs control original when cloned

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a use case where i need to create a series of "cards" with tabs on top (so each card has tabs).  To achieve this, I intended on having a template element which I clone and then populate.  This works as expected, EXCEPT for the tabs on the cloned elements, when clicked they control the original template object instead of the current clone.

I'm assuming this is due to the event listeners that have been cloned are still connected to the original object?  Is there some way to disconnect them and ensure they point and at the newly cloned objects?

Example code below...

```js
document.querySelector("#add_card").addEventListener("click", add_card);

function add_card() {
  let clone = document.querySelector('.mytab.template').cloneNode(true)
  document.querySelector('#card_list').appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container py-3">
  <header>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
      <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_card">Add Card</button>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 mb-4 text-left" id="card_list">
      <div class="col mytab template">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm ">
          <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-pills nav-pills">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" data-bs-toggle="tab" href=".one">one</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href=".two">two</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane one active">
              <h1>ONE</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane two">
              <h1>Two</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is that tab targets must have unique identifiers. You'd have the same problem if you were to duplicate the markup itself. Here's how you might do that. Notice that I've moved the template to simplify the operation.

```js
let iterator = 0;
document.querySelector("#add_card").addEventListener("click", add_card);

function add_card() {
  let clone = document.querySelector('.template').cloneNode(true);

  // add unique classes to each pane element
  clone.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane').forEach((el, i) => {
    el.classList.add('tab_' + iterator + i);
  });

  clone.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((el, i) => {
    // update href attributes on each tab element to match panes
    el.setAttribute('href', '.tab_' + iterator + i);

    // initialize Bootstrap tabs on each tab element
    const tab = new bootstrap.Tab(el)

    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      tab.show();
    })
  });

  // append the clone
  document.querySelector('#card_list').appendChild(clone);

  // show the clone
  clone.classList.remove('d-none');

  iterator++;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container py-3">
  <header>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
      <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_card">Add Card</button>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 mb-4 text-left" id="card_list">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm ">
          <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-pills nav-pills">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true" data-bs-toggle="tab" href=".one">one</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href=".two">two</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane one active">
              <h1>ONE</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane two">
              <h1>Two</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<div class="col template d-none">
  <div class="card mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm ">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-pills nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="true">one</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">two</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active">
        <h1>ONE</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane">
        <h1>Two</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```